# I cannot get value from an object in blade template Laravel 4

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent, laravel-blade

I have a loop foreach in a blade template where i print data from a specific model, the problem is I am not able of getting the value of "$pedido->proveedor()->first()->name" in the code giveing me this error "ErrorException (E_UNKNOWN) Trying to get property of non-object (View: C:..":

```
@foreach($pedidos as $pedido)  
    <tr>
        <td>
            {{ $pedido->id }}
        </td>
        <td>
           {{ $pedido->proveedor()->first()->name }}
        </td>
        <td>
          {{ date('d/m/Y', $pedido->fecha) }}
        </td>

          <td>
            <a onclick="return confirm('deseas borar este registro?')" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs fullButton">Borrar</a>
         </td>
     </tr>
@endforeach
```

The weird thing here is when I code this "$pedido->proveedor()->first()" in side the loop of the template I get an object like this:

```
      {"name":"nombre","domicilio":"domicilio","cp":"46006","poblacion":"poblacion","ciudad":"ciudad","pais":"pais"}
```

but coding this "$pedido->proveedor()->first()->name" I get the error:

the data is sent from a controller:

```
public function listPedidos()
{   

    $pedidos = Pedido::all();
//  this next pice of code shows me i can get the name as spected but only from php
//  foreach($pedidos as $pedido){
//     ddd($pedido->proveedor()->first()->name);exit;
//  }
    return View::make('pedidos/pedidos-list')->with('pedidos', $pedidos);

}
```

Another weirder thing is that I have the same code with different model and it is working.

Thanks in advance for any help. ;)

Comment: Can you show us the `proveedor()` function?

Comment: public function proveedor(){
  return $this->belongsTo('Proveedor', 'idProveedor');
}

Answer (score 2):

You should use:

```
{{ $pedido->proveedor->name }}
```

Comment: thanks for answering, 
that code seems to show the proper result for a moment but quickly the screen changes and throws me this:"
Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \ FatalErrorException (E_ERROR)
Call to a member function first() on a non-object
"

Comment: same as the begining:
 "ErrorException (E_UNKNOWN)
Trying to get property of non-object (Vew:.."
although this: "{{ $pedido->proveedor }}" gives me the whole object {"name":"nombre","domicilio":"domicilio","cp":"46006","poblacion":"poblacion","ciudad":"ciudad","pais":"pais"}

Comment: @user2957058 Are you sure you don't have any column in your table with name `proveedor` ?

Comment: **Pedidos Table:**
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `pedidos` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `observaciones` text,
  ` **idProveedor** ` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=9 ;



**Proveedor Table:**
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `proveedores` (
  `name` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
  `domicilio` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `cp` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=4 ;

Comment: I only have **idProveedor** as a foreing key in pedidos table, also I have in pedido Model as a relationship: `public function proveedor(){
  return $this->belongsTo('Proveedor', 'idProveedor');
 }` and this: `public function pedido(){
  return $this->hasMany('Pedido', 'idProveedor');
 }` in proveedor Model

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved:

the previos answer was ok. I can use:

```
{{ $pedido->proveedor()->first()->name }}
```

or

```
{{ $pedido->proveedor->name }}
```

but because in one of the way of the loop there was not content to refer to i.e($pedido->proveedor didn't exixt) I use this:

```
{{ isset($pedido->Proveedor->name )?$pedido->Proveedor->name :''; }}
```